# Is there any difference in these three sentences?

Tags: tenses

> I will buy a car tomorrow
>
> I'm gonna buy a car tomorrow
>
> I'm buying a car tomorrow

I know there are three ways to express future in English. In my knowledge, first one can be used when you sure about your action and the second one can be used in the near future. However I'm not sure how and when to use the third sentence. Is it just same as the second one for native speakers?

Comment: You missed out *I will be buying it tomorrow, I shall buy it tomorrow,* and *I buy it tomorrow* (and probably other constructions with exactly or approximately the same meaning).

Comment: Also: *I am to buy it tomorrow*, *I am about to buy it (tomorrow)*....

Comment: This question is basic enough that it probably belongs on English Learners Stack Exchange, not here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Not really, they all imply the same thing. A few minor differences would be:

Nobody would say "I will buy a car tomorrow" in normal conversation.

"I'm gonna buy a car tomorrow" is pretty informal.

"I'm buying a car tomorrow" is formal.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know third one is formal.

Comment: @loone96 well it’s formal as in it’s definitely not informal. You wouldn’t talk like that to your friends if you know what I mean?

Comment: "I'm buying a car tomorrow" is definitely not formal. "I *am* buying a car tomorrow" is less informal, but still informal. The most formal construction for what you are trying to say is "I will buy a car tomorrow," but a slightly less formal one, "I am going to buy a car tomorrow," makes much more sense. The formality isn't the issue, though. "Going to" indicates more certainty than "will," which sounds weird here because buying a car is a major purchase requiring careful consideration. It would (hopefully) be pretty certain the day before! Contrast "I will buy you a lollipop tomorrow, Timmy."